# Selenium IDE - Extension using .js file - Error

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

This is my first post as I am a newbie to Selenium. Currently I am going through book called Selenium tool : beginners guide. In the book it tells how to use Selenium IDE Extension using .js file to store your JS functions etc.

Following example was given and and saved as user-extension.js file. I have defined file in Selenium > Option > Selenium IDE extension field.

But when I re-start selenium I am getting following error:

```
"error loading Selenium IDE extensions: ReferenceError: Selenium is not defined"
```

Example I am using is:

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeTodaysDate = function(locator){
    var dates = new Date();
    var day = dates.getDate();
    if (day < 10){
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    month = dates.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10){
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    var year = dates.getFullYear();
    var prettyDay = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    this.doType(locator, prettyDay);
}
```

any help will much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Selenium IDE Extensions.  And browse to the same file from the Selenium Core Extensions instead.  That will solve your problem.  I reproduced your error on my browser.  Your code was fine.